# Baking problem (selected to active- cycles)

Tags: texture-baking

so I've modelled a high poly character and then i retopologized it using shrinkwrap. So then I followed Andrew Price tutorial on youtube how to bake normals from high poly mesh to low poly by selecting both of them and leaving the low poly mesh selected last (active). But from the whole character just one hand baked i dont understand why. Anyone have any sugestions?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I already figured it out. I left [Mask modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/mask.html) on my high poly mesh. I had to delete it in order to continue baking all highpoly meshes onto the lwopoly.